# Unable to configure mindmeld to remote elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, mindmeld

I am trying to configure my mindmeld chatbot to use remote elastic search instead of local, but I could not find any example that changes the default localhost:9200 elastic search  to remote elastic search

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming a unix-like environment) if your es server is located at `https://foo.bar.es.amazonaws.com/` set the env var `MM_ES_HOST` like so (for bash):

```sh
export MM_ES_HOST="https://foo.bar.es.amazonaws.com/"
```

Run this prior to running any mindmeld commands and it should be able to find your server.